# How to disable TCP checksum validation on Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tcp, checksum

For some reason, I want to disable TCP checksum validation on my Linux host. Is that possible to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

you can using `ethtool` command example to disable checksum offload
`ethtool -K eth0 tx off rx off`

Comment: ... but the kernel will still validate checksums.

Comment: I want to disable TCP checksum validation, not checksum offloading.

Comment: You might want to use UDP protocol instead.